# Как получить VKApiUser с помощью VKSDK?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, request, global-variables

Во время использования VK-API наткнулся на проблему при вызове метода:

```
public VKApiUser getUserData(int id)
{
    VKApiUser userData;  // <---- Нельзя декларировать подобным образом

    VKParameters params = new VKParameters();
    params.put(VKApiConst.USER_IDS, id);

    VKRequest yourRequest = VKApi.users().get(params);
    yourRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            userData = ((VKList<VKApiUser>)response.parsedModel).get(0);
            Log.d("User: ", userData.first_name + " " + userData.last_name);
            super.onComplete(response);
        }
    });

    return userData;  //Нужно дождаться окончания присвоения userData в "onComplete" 
}
```

Идея:
Мною вызывается "getUserData(id)" из другого метода таким образом, что он возвращает переменную userData по закрытии request.

Проблема:
Проблема заключается в получении переменной, присвоенной в void "onComplete", а также в определении момента, когда request окончен.

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Пожалуйтса, задайте вопрос на русском языке (воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" для изменения вопроса)

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса так как сайт предназначен для общения на русском языке.

Comment: Переведено на русский язык

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. вы не можете немедленно получить нужные данные то вы не сможете написать метод, возвращающий их. Вам надо переделать логику получения данных с учётом их асинхронного получения.

А это строка

> VKApiUser userData;  // <---- Can't declare like that.

не верна, т.к. далее вы обращаетесь к ней в анонимном внутреннем классе. Для обращения к внешним переменным внутри анонимного внутреннего класса переменная должна быть либо `final` либо быть полем внешнего класса.

---

И да, т.к. мы `StackOferflow на русском` то и вопросы надо писать на русском.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, я обратил внимание на асинхронность процесса. Было бы неплохо понять, каким образом организовать ожидание получения данных.

Comment: @MikhailKolesnikov, в двух словах не объяснишь, тем паче, что информации мало. Вам надо что-то типа `AsyncTask`-a пользовать. Ну и ещё раз доки прочитать)